# Writing from a BinaryWriter to a byte[]

Tags: c#

quick question. I'm trying to convert an integer to a 7BitEncodedInt through the Binary Writer. Currently it seems the best manner I have to do so is the following:

```
Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
InternalBinaryWriter ibw = new InternalBinaryWriter(memoryStream);
ibw.Write7BitEncodedInt((int)length);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
memoryStream.Read(object.ByteArray, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
```

Is there a simpler way to do so without requiring the streams? I'm slightly reluctant to reimplement their Write7BitEncodedInt function and just have that output directly to a byte array, but if necessary that's just what I'll do

edit:

What I ended up doing was the following:

```
the byteArray is resized accordingly, just didn't include that line in the source.
```

What I ended up doing was the following:

```
    byte[] Write7BitEncodedIntToByteArray(int length) {
        List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();
        while (length > 0x80) {
            byteList.Add((byte)(length | 0x80));
            length >>= 7;
        }
        byteList.Add((byte)length);
        return byteList.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: There is no way to get rid of the streams if Write7BitEncodingInt uses streams.  MemoryStream is the way to go.

Comment: Alright, thanks. What I think I'll end up doing is just reimplement the function to write to a byte array intermediary and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write to a `byte[]` array, using a `MemoryStream` is the easiest way to do it.  In fact, one of the `MemoryStream` constructors takes a byte array and uses that as the buffer it will write to.  So it might be more useful in your case to do something like this:

```
using( var memoryStream = new MemoryStream( @object.ByteArray ) )
using( var writer = new InternalBinaryWriter( memoryStream ) )
{
    writer.Write7BitEncodedInt( (int) length );
}
```

Keep in mind that this will result in a memory stream that cannot expand its size.  Based on the code you supplied I think this will be fine (what you've shown may in fact throw an exception at runtime if `@object.ByteArray` is smaller than the stream array).

EDIT: Since we're looking at evidently performance-critical code, I tested three different methods:

### List

```
static byte[] MethodA( int length )
{
    List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();
    while (length > 0x80) {
        byteList.Add((byte)(length | 0x80));
        length >>= 7;
    }
    byteList.Add((byte)length);
    return byteList.ToArray();
}
```

### MemoryStream

```
static byte[] MethodB( int length )
{
    using( var stream = new MemoryStream( 5 ) )
    {
        while( length > 0x80 )
        {
            stream.WriteByte( (byte) ( length | 0x80 ) );
            length >>= 7;
        }
        stream.WriteByte( (byte) length );
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

### Direct Array

```
static byte[] MethodC( int length )
{
    int tmp = length;
    int l = 1;
    while( ( tmp >>= 7 ) > 0 ) ++l;

    var result = new byte[l];
    for( int i = 0; i < l; ++i )
    {
        result[i] = (byte) ( 0x80 | length );
        length >>= 7;
    }

    result[l - 1] &= 0x7f;

    return result;
}
```

By a wide margin, the third method was the fastest (4-5x faster than the previous two).  When it comes to performance critical code, creating a `List` just to turn it into an array is almost always a smell, which is what got my attention here.

It's also possible that another big chunk of time could be getting sucked up elsewhere depending on how this method is used (for example, if this small array is being copied into a larger array every time, you might be able to remove the array allocations altogether and write directly into the larger array).

Comment: the byteArray is resized accordingly, just didn't include that line in the source.

Posting what I ended up doing in a separate reply, can't seem to format the comments correctly.

Comment: @user2864757 I'm not sure why it's important to avoid the stream in this case.  Even if you want the array to resize `MemoryStream` has a `ToArray` method itself which will pop out the written array.

Comment: It's more to do with having as little overhead as physically possible. I'm calling this method upwards of 100k times a second and need it to be as trim as possible. Having the streams just adds a little more overhead I don't need

Comment: @user2864757 What makes you think a `MemoryStream` has more overhead than instantiating a new `List` each time?  A `MemoryStream` is just a thin wrapper around a `byte[]` that manages resizing itself as it's written to.  It sounds like you're prematurely optimizing.

Comment: Using the memory stream method takes a little more than 4.5x as long as the List -> Array method. When time's most critical, I can't afford that.

I ran each test 100,000 times. Method one (stream) took 17.8s in total, method two (list -> array) took 4.2s in total. While perhaps the stream is slightly less in memory overhead, the list method is by far the better performer.

Comment: @user2864757 I don't know how you got that result, but I can't reproduce it.  I tested it myself and using a `MemoryStream` was slightly faster than a `List` every time (by about 10% if you give the stream an appropriate starting capacity).  My best guess is that your speed discrepancy comes about due to whatever writer implementation you're using, not the `MemoryStream` itself.